# OPENERP: ValidateError Error occurred while validating the field(s) arch: Invalid XML for View Architecture

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I'm new to programming for OpenERP 7.0, When you import this module to OpenERP gives me an error:ValidateError Error occurred while validating the field(s) arch: Invalid XML for View Architecture!. I`m not locate the error. 
I would be very grateful if you help me. thanks.

**_*init*_.py**

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

import tipos_acceso_kaicen
```

**_*openerp*_.py**

```
{
"name" : "Tipos Acceso Kaicen",
"version" : "1.0",
"author" : "Kaicen",
"category" : "Gestionar tipos de acceso",
"website" : "http://www.kacien.es",
"description": "Podremos dar de alta los tipos de acceso de los que disfrutarán nuestros socios",
"depends" : ["base"],
"init_xml" : ["tipos_acceso_kaicen_view.xml"],
"demo xml" : [],
"update_xml" : ["tipos_acceso_kaicen_view.xml"],
"active": False,
"installable": True,
"data": ["tipos_acceso_kaicen_view.xml"]
}
```

**tipos_acceso_kaicen.py**

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

from osv import osv, fields
from tools.translate import _


class aceso_tipoacceso(osv.osv):
 _name = 'acceso.tipoacceso'

  _columns = {
                           'tipo_acceso': fields.char('Tipo Acceso', size=140, required = True),
                           'product.id':fields.many2one('product.product', 'Artículo', required = True),
                           'numaccesos_tiempo':fields.boolean('numaccesos_tiempo'),
                           'cantidad':fields.integer('cantidad'),
                           'sale_pack_type': fields.selection((('a', 'A'), ('b', 'B'), ('c', 'C')), 'Sale Packaging Type')
                }
aceso_tipoacceso()
```

**tipos_acceso_kaicen_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
 <data>
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_acceso_tipoacceso_tree">
        <field name="name">acceso.tipoacceso.tree</field>
        <field name="model">acceso.tipoacceso</field>
        <field name="type">tree</field>            
        <field name="arch" type="xml">               
                <tree String="Tipos de Acceso">         
                           <field name="tipo_acceso"/>
                           <field name="product.id"/>
                           <field name="numaccesos_tiempo"/>
                           <field name="cantidad"/>
               </tree>                
        </field>
    </record> 
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_acceso_tipoacceso_form">
        <field name="name">acceso.tipoacceso.form</field>
        <field name="model">acceso.tipoacceso</field>
        <field name="type">form</field>            
        <field name="arch" type="xml">               
                <form String="Tipos de Acceso">       
                           <field name="tipo_acceso"/>
                           <field name="product.id"/>
                           <field name="numaccesos_tiempo"/>
                           <field name="cantidad"/>
                           <field name="sale_pack_type"/>
               </form>                
        </field>
    </record>   
<!--Accion disparador tipo acceso  -->
<record model ="ir.actions.act_window" id="open_view_acceso_tipoacceso_form">
            <field name="name"> Tipo Acceso</field>
            <field name="res_model">acceso.tipoacceso</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
</record>
<!--opcion del menu para tipo acceso  -->
<menuitem id="menu_acceso_tipoacceso_open_view_form" name="Tipo acceso" parent="base.menu_base_partner" action="open_view_acceso_tipoacceso_form"/>    
</data>
</openerp>
```

Comment: There is no error description, no real question

Comment: When you import this module to OpenERP gives me an error:ValidateError Error occurred while validating the field(s) arch: Invalid XML for View Architecture!. I`m not locate the error.

Answer (score 1):

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_acceso_tipoacceso_form">
    <field name="name">acceso.tipoacceso.form</field>
    <field name="model">acceso.tipoacceso</field>
    <field name="type">form</field>            
    <field name="arch" type="xml">               
            <form String="Tipos de Acceso" version="7.0"> <!--You forgot to write version attribute -->   
                       <field name="tipo_acceso"/>
                       <field name="product.id"/>
                       <field name="numaccesos_tiempo"/>
                       <field name="cantidad"/>
                       <field name="sale_pack_type"/>
           </form>                
    </field>
</record>
```

In OpenERP 7.0 you must have to write its form view version

Comment: I tried before with version = "7.0", but still gives me the same error.

Thanks Ronak, but there must be something else.  I keep reviewing it and I see nothing wrong.

Comment: Update String="Tipos de Acceso" to string="Tipos de Acceso".
solved!